# How do I assign a series to one part of a dataframe column and another series to the other part of the dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I'm cleaning a dataframe column of dates and I wrote a function that cleans some entries in some way and cleans all other entries in another way.

I'm getting the data cleaned and in two separate series. I've recorded the index position of each entry from the original column and I know which indices are in each of the two clean series.

My trouble is assigning both series together to the dataframe column. I just can't do it.

My function f receives the dates column and returns a list of 4: Indices of column in the first series [0], clean entries in the first series[1], indices of column in the second series[2], clean entries in the second series[3].

So when I do f(column)[3] and f(column)[1] I do get cleaned pandas series.

```
#Function works:

>>> f(df['dates_column'])[0]
, 18812, 18813, 18814, 18815, 18816, 18817, 18818, 18819, 18820, 18821, 
18822, 18823, 18824, 18825, 18826,

>>> f(df['dates_column'])[1].tail()
331849   2009-10-03
331850   2006-10-03
331851   2015-09-27
331852   1911-08-09
331853   2013-09-03
Name: dates_column, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> f(df['dates_column'])[3].tail()
331898   1996-12-11
331899   2004-06-01
331900   2010-03-12
331901   2016-01-06
331902   2010-03-12
Name: dates_column, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> f(df['dates_column'])[1].head()    
0   1900-01-01
1   1900-01-01
2   1900-01-01
3   1900-01-01
4   1900-01-01
Name: dates_column, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> f(df['dates_column'])[3].head()
40036   2002-06-18
40037   2005-04-01
40038   2002-04-01
40039   2003-05-02
40040   2006-10-01
Name: dates_column, dtype: datetime64[ns]

#But cannot assign properly..

>>> df['dates_column'][function(df['dates_column'])[0]] = 
f(df['dates_column'])[1]

<input>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

>>> df['dates_column'][f(df['dates_column'])[2]] = 
f(df['dates_column'])[3]

<input>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

#And it gets all crazy in the head..
>>> df['dates_column'].head()
0    -2208988800000000000
1    -2208988800000000000
2    -2208988800000000000
3    -2208988800000000000
4    -2208988800000000000
Name: dates_column, dtype: object

#And in the tail 
>>> df['dates_column'].tail()
31898     1996-12-11 00:00:00
331899    2004-06-01 00:00:00
331900    2010-03-12 00:00:00
331901    2016-01-06 00:00:00
331902    2010-03-12 00:00:00
Name: dates_column, dtype: object
```

How do I assign the values on both series to dates_column? I can't understand change of format either

Comment: IIUC , you may want to check `pd.series.update()` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html)

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem - what's the starting state and what are you trying to get to? it seems to me like function `f` is not the right way to approach this, but it's tough to tell what you're ultimately trying to do.